# Different types JSON file using ObjectMapper

Tags: json, swift, subclass, alamofire, objectmapper

I am using AlamofireObjectMapper to communicate with a backend server. The result of one of the requests is an array of items, which contain two values:

- A "typeIdentifier" indicating which type of data the second value ("arbitraryData") is of
- A "arbitraryData":

  - If "typeIdentifier" CONTAINS "X", arbitraryData is of type ArbitraryDataTypeX
  - If "typeIdentifier" CONTAINS "Y", arbitraryData is of type ArbitraryDataTypeY

The two ArbitraryDataType classes do not share any common ancestor (except Mappable). It could be even a primitive type, an array, an optional, etc.

How can I make AlamofireObjectMapper parse the "arbitraryData" field using the appropriate type.

See the following JSON file:

```
{
    "arrayOfItems": [
        {
            "typeIdentifier": "X",
            "arbitraryData":
                {
                    "value": "BLA",
                }
        },
        {
            "typeIdentifier": "Y",
            "arbitraryData":
                {
                    "anotherValue": "BLUBB",
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

My corresponding Swing file looks like the following:

```
class Item : Mapping {
    var typeIdentifier = "X"
    var arbitraryData: Mappable? = nil

    init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        typeIdentifier <- map["typeIdentifier"]

        // THIS LINE CONTAINS MY QUESTION: HOW CAN I TELL OBJECTMAPPER, THAT,
        // IF typeIdentifier CONTAINS "X", arbitraryData IS OF TYPE
        // ArbitraryDataTypeX, AND IF "Y" arbitraryData IS OF TYPE
        // ArbitraryDataTypeY?
        arbitraryData <- map["arbitraryData"]
    }
}

class ArbitraryDataTypeX : Mapping {
    var value = "BLA"

    init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        value <- map["value"]
    }
}

class ArbitraryDataTypeY : Mapping {
    var anotherValue = "BLUBB"

    init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        anotherValue <- map["anotherValue"]
    }
}
```

Background information: I am using AlamofireObjectMapper to communicate with a backend server. The result of one of the requests is an array of Item. The typeIdentifier-mechanism (infact it is a little bit more complex, but let's leave this out) is given by the backend and cannot be changed.

Comment: What is the question you seek answer to ?

Comment: Sorry, this indeed was unclear. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution (I don't know why I didn't see it from the beginning):

```
// This is Item.map()
func mapping(map: Map) {
    typeIdentifier <- map["typeIdentifier"]

    switch typeIdentifier {
    case "X":
        let x: X?
        x <- map["arbitraryData"]
        arbitraryData = x
    case "Y":
        let y: Y?
        y <- map["arbitraryData"]
        arbitraryData = y
    default:
        arbitraryData = nil
    }
}
```